# Read jack splitter as two separate devices

Tags: windows-10, audio, multiple-monitors, sound-card, headphone-jack

I ran out of jack output connectors on my pc, and I recently bought a [jack splitter](https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B07K44B7HL) to connect another sound card (my second monitor which requires a VGA connection).

The problem is, and I can't figure out how I didn't think about it in the first place, that Windows reads the splitter as a unique device. This means that if I select that output as my playback device, it will come out from both the devices simultaneously.

Is there any way to make the splitter act like two separate devices? If not, how can I accomplish that same result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The splitter ***is*** a unique device. You have one plug hard-wired to two. How on earth is anything going to treat this monolithic structure as two individual devices? You'd need a hardware mixer in the chain.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know I know... That's why I said that I couldn't figure out how I didn't think about it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The splitter is literally just three wires soldered to each other – it doesn't have any active or even passive circuitry beyond that. So it is impossible for your sound card to send the signal in such a way that it would only travel down one leg of the Y-split but not the other.

Instead, you can get a second sound card – either one that goes into a PCI/PCIe slot, or one connected via USB (appears to be more commonly called "USB DAC"). This will be visible to the OS as an independent device with its own outputs (and inputs).

Alternatively, it *may* be possible to reconfigure one of your audio input jacks (e.g. the "Line In" jack) as an additional output. Jack retasking is a common feature of HD Audio chipsets, and you might find it e.g. in the "Realtek HD Audio" settings panel.

---

*(Note: At least in the past, installing a PCI sound card often used to automatically disable the built-in one. I don't know if this is still the case with modern computers.)*

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I'll try with jack retasking (if you have any guides to link here it would be appreciated)... And in case of failure, I'll buy a new internal sound card. Greetings.